# How does this code works in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I participated in Codeforces Round #396 (Div. 2) yesterday.
The (A) problem seemed pretty advanced in my opinion when I read it.
I tried solving it all the competition time yesterday and some time today.
I came up with a 200 lines long(half-working) solution. And then I gave up.

I looked what other people wrote there and I saw max 20 lines long code that seems magic to me.

The problem asks you to output the length of the longest uncommon subsequence of letters from two strings.
You can read the full problem here:
http://codeforces.com/contest/766/problem/A

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
string a,b;
int main(){
    cin>>a>>b;
    printf("%d",a==b?-1:max(a.size(),b.size()));
    return 0;
}
```

This is all the code used to solve the problem, and I really want to know how that one line of code

```
printf("%d",a==b?-1:max(a.size(),b.size()));
```

can solve this "advanced" task?

Comment: All this does is compare the strings for equality, and if they're not equal, output the larger one. Why that solves the problem is something for you to think about :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The [foo]?[bar]:[baj] is ternary equivalent to: if([foo]) then output bar; else output baj;

Comment: @AndyG: I don't think it actually solves the problem, see my answer.

Comment: @MartinUeding sure it does, I can't say I agree with your answer. Pete Beckers answer is perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two strings are equal, there is no "uncommon subsequence". If they are not equal, neither one is a subsequence of the other, but each one is a subsequence of itself, so each one is an "uncommon subsequence". The longer of the two is the longest "uncommon subsequence", and its length is the correct answer. If the two are not equal but have the same length, then each one is an "uncommon subsequence" and the length of the longest is just the length of either one.

Don't get tangled up in what you (or any other reasonable person) think a "subsequence" is. The problem defines "uncommon subsequence", and all you have to do is apply its definition. This "problem" is about word play, not coding.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to solve the task at hand. It just outputs `-1` when the strings are equal and the length of the longer string when they are not different. However, the problem asks for the longest uncommon sequence. It would fail with the inputs `abc` and `abcd` to give the answer `1` would rather give `4`.

What the line does is the following:

- It checks whether `a == b`, whether the strings are equal.
- If they are equal, the condition `A` is true in the *ternary operator* `A ? B : C`, so that expression will evaluate to `B` which is just `-1` here.
- If they are not equal, it will evaluate to `C` which is the maximum of the two string lengths, so it will be length of the longer string.
- The value of the ternary expression is then printed, albeit without a newline, which is a bit bad.

So the code is so short because it only solves the problem for a few cases but not the general case.

Comment: `"abcd"` is a subsequence of itself, and it is not a subsequence of `"abc"`, so it is the longest "uncommon subsequence".

Comment: I read the problem statement such that there is no order to it, but both inputs are on equal footing. So `abc` is a subsequence of `abcd`, and the longest uncommon subsequence is `d` therefore.

Comment: `"d"` is **an** "uncommon subsequence", but it it not the only one. The question asks for the length of the **longest** one, and the longest one is `"abcd"`.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. So indeed, this question is about word play.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf ("%d", a == b ? -1 : max (a.size (), b.size ()));
```

is equivalent to

```
if (a == b) {
    printf ("%d", -1);
}
else {
    if (a.size () > b.size ()) {
        printf ("%d", a.size ());
    }
    else {
        printf ("%d", b.size());
    }
}
```

BTW That's only a small step in solving the problem...

[CORRECTION]

IT DOES SOLVE THE WHOLE PROBLEM (See answer of Pete Becker)

Comment: Well, but it is accepted :d

Comment: That's too bad, I've read the original assignment via your link, and the tiny code fragment certainly doesn't solve it. BTW you're speaking about 20 lines of code? But the fragment has only 8 lines.

Comment: What would be the correct solution?
By the way, don't judge me, I am not as advanced as you guys are :(

Comment: I certainly don't judge you! Seems you seriously tried. Could you show us your own code?

Comment: Okay, I can show it.
But I am thinking now, that maybe I didn't understand the task correctly...
http://pastebin.com/hMJyU5Ah

Comment: Hi Reinards, you did understand it correctly and I was wrong!! @Pete Becker has the right answer!!

Comment: Okay! At lest next time I will do better :)